# Laravel change manually pivot value

Tags: php, laravel, pivot, relationship, laravel-5

i have one model Capacity which stores statistical data. One Capacity belongs from 0 to many Model Operators. I have the problem to show the form for input the data, when some Capacity does not have any Operators. I need explicit to set the $operator->id to be 0 when there is no Operator.
Unfortunately the list of Operators to one Capacity i store in pivot table and i do not know how to simulate that.

In my Capacity model i have:

```
public function operators() {

    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Operator', 'capacity_operator_relation')
    ->withPivot('id')
    ->withTimestamps();

}
```

in my blade template i have this check:

```
@if(!$capacity->operators) 
    // here i need to set an array with one operator, which id = 0
    $operator->pivot->id = 0;
@endif
@foreach($capacity->operators as $operator)
    <input type="hidden" name="operator" value="{{ $operator->pivot-id }}">
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help:

```
@if(!$capacity->operators) 
    @foreach($capacity->operators as $operator)
        <input type="hidden" name="operators[]" value="{{ $operator->pivot-id }}">
    @endforeach
@else
<input type="hidden" name="operators[]" value="0">
@endif
```